# Substitue to Insert query for more than 200,000 records in mysql db table

Tags: mysql, insert-query

I have to insert more than 200000 records at one go, into mysql db table, Insert query is resulting in performance issue, what could be the substitute to this.

Below is the code I am using

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("247electrical.xml");

foreach($xml->merchant as $merchant){

define('API', 'PS');
require_once('constants.inc.php');
require_once('classes/class.ClientFactory.php');
$oClient = ClientFactory::getClient(API_USERNAME, API_PASSWORD, API_USER_TYPE); $merchattrs=$merchant->attributes();
$aParams100 = array('iMerchantId' => array($merchattrs->id)); $merchantinfo= $oClient->call('getMerchant', $aParams100);

//Get Products

foreach($xml->merchant->prod as $product){

$attrs=$product->attributes();

//Insert Products into DB
mysql_query('INSERT INTO productstemp (merchant_id, merchant_name, aw_product_id, merchant_product_id, product_name, description, category_id, merchant_category, aw_deep_link, aw_image_url, search_price, delivery_cost, merchant_image_url, aw_thumb_url, brand_name, delivery_time, display_price, in_stock, merchant_thumb_url, model_number, pre_order, stock_quantity, store_price, valid_from, valid_to, web_offer, merchantimage, cleancompany) VALUES("'.$merchattrs->id.'","'.$merchattrs->name.'","'.$attrs->id.'"," ","'.$product->text->name.'","'.$product->text->desc.'","'.$product->cat->awCatId.'","'.$product->cat->mCat.'","'.$product->uri->awTrack.'","'.$product->uri->awImage.'","'.$product->price->buynow.'","'.$product->price->delivery.'","'.$product->uri->mImage.'","'.$product->uri->awThumb.'","'.$product->brand->brandName.'","'.$product->delTime.'","'.$product->price->buynow.'","'.$attrs->in_stock.'","'.$product->uri->mThumb.'","'.$product->modelNumber.'","'.$attrs->pre_order.'","'.$attrs->stock_quantity.'","'.$product->price->store.'","'.$product->valFrom.'","'.$product->valTo.'","'.$attrs->web_offer.'","'.$merchantinfo->oMerchant->sLogoUrl.'","247electrical" ) ')
or die(mysql_error());     

}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't get it, the only way to put that info into your DB is with an insert, so what is your question?

Comment: its a cron job to in which I am already using an insert query in a PHP foreach loop which is making the script slow, so i need another workaround to get this done without slowing down the process

Comment: why don't you use a Mysql TASK to import a file with all those rows? or create a cronjob that call a procedure that import the file to the DB?

Comment: It is importing the values from xml and then iterating the foreach loop to insert

Comment: you can import XML to your DB, but I not sure if that will works for your XML

Comment: lemme update my question with my code, please chk my question back again for the code

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that the INSERT queries per se are the problem. 200.000 inserts arent that much for mysql after all.

First I guess reading the file is slow. SimpleXML is convenient but for large files it results in a huge memory overhead. Think about a streaming XML reader like PHP´s [XMLReader](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php).

You are sending individual statements to the mysql server which is way slower then sending one huge statement. Also, your single insert statement should be wrapped in a transaction. What happens if you processed 10.000 records and inserted them and then your script dies/mysql server dies etc.? How do you safely start the script again without manual work (clearing table, lookup which were already processed etc.).

Apart from that, one single INSERT statement with many VALUES should be way faster. I would make your PHP script output the query so it looks in the end like this:

```
INSERT INTO table(field_1, field_2, field 3)
VALUES('foo 1', 'bar 1', 'baz 1'),
VALUES('foo 2', 'bar 2', 'baz 2'),
...
```

And then import that file via:

```
$ mysql ... credentials options etc ... < output.sql
```

If thats still too slow… buying more hardware might help, too.